# How to load mock data from JSON file in Angular 2 karma jasmine test?

Tags: json, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am writing **karma jasmine** test case for **angular 2**,

And we came across requirement to mock data in separate JSON file as data is huge (want to make sure code cleanness). For this I searched a lot but didn't find proper solution.

We already mocking HTTP service using **MockBackend**, So we can't use HTTP service of angular to load JSON as it eventually request will go to MockBackend.

So is there any another way without using any third party lib like
jasmine-jquery or   Karma-jasmine-preprocessor ? ***More kind of Angular JS 2 way***.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had the same issue!

Finally, I realized that just using the `require()` function directly in TypeScript works just fine. It is supported by Node and @types/node, otherwise some need to declare require types.

So to load mock data from JSON file in Angular 2 Karma Jasmine test, go for:

```
const data: any = require('../../assets/mock-data.json');
```

PS: [credits to Artur Ampilogov](https://medium.com/@a_ampilogov/another-simple-way-is-just-using-require-funciton-directly-in-typescript-3dd3ebe38491)

Comment: I have a problem with this.
if I do
const data: any = require('../../assets/mock-data.json');
const data1: any = require('../../assets/mock-data.json'); then data and data1 are copied by reference. If I try to use spread operator to copy by value
const data: any = {...require('../../assets/mock-data.json')};
 it does not work. Still referencing each other.

Comment: This is a really bad approach as it caches the response so if you mock this data for example for a http response and do any change logic on the data being used, it will change this value under the hood. Try to avoid require for loading JSON files for testing.

Comment: Had the same issue, was quite hard to reproduce since my environments shuffle the order of the tests, sometimes I had an error, sometimes not. A better way hence is to use `const data: any = Object.assign({}, require('../../assets/mock-data.json'));` as it copies the object over into a new one first.

Comment: But how to load load data as observable from JSON file ?

When we are mocking service for reading JSON data from file, REQUIRE is not working

Comment: Should test data be placed in assets folder? As I understand assets folder will be included in production build.

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the typescript compiler to load in json files, by specifying

```
--resolveJsonModule
```

Or by adding

```
"resolveJsonModule": true
```

to the compilerOptions property of tsconfig.json

Then, in your spec file, you can import the json file into a variable as follows:

```
import * as myJson from './test/myJson.json';
```

You can then access it in a test, e.g.:

```
it('it should let me access properties from my json file', () => {
    expect(myJson.myProperty).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: I believe this is the more up-to-date correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't work in all cases as it doesn't work properly if an array is the top level object in the JSON file. - https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37831

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the same. `System.import` works if you pass the path of the JSON like this:

```
System.import('../../assets/mock-data/mock-data.json')
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

What is really weird, is that I didn't manage to make it work with variables:

```
let myUrl: string = '../../assets/mock-data/mock-data.json';
System.import(myUrl)
    .then((json) => {
        console.log(json);
    });`
```

Comment: That make sense, since System.import like require and ES6 import etc.. are read staticaly (in compile time) without code evaluation, so you cannot use varible or code to generate the path (like 'src' + '/assets' or getPath(), etc..).