# How to import json file to be available in angular-cli npm test

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, angular-cli

Given angular version 4.2.4 with angular-cli (version 1.1.3) and following code:

```
import languagesJsonRaw from './languages/en.json';
import countriesJsonRaw from './countries/en.json';

export const languages = prepareLanguages(languagesJsonRaw);
export const countries = prepareCountries(countriesJsonRaw);
```

This works when I run `npm start` (which triggers `ng serve`) - `languages` and `countries` are available to the application.

When I run `npm test`, which basically triggers:

```
ng test --reporters dots,html --browsers Chrome --watch
```

then `languagesJsonRaw` and `countriesJsonRaw` are undefined.

How can I provide those files also to the test runner? I don't think we needed to do anything special for them to be available from `ng serve` or `ng build`, works even with AOT.

It's default angular-cli project, so test runner is karma I think.

**Github Issue**: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6786

Comment: I've never import json like that, I always make a http.get to the path of the json, I suppose it should work

Comment: Hey, did you sort out this problem? If not, got a suggestion for your code, I think you should change the way you do the imports of those json files, something like:
import * as json from './languages/en.json';... maybe it's already too late

Comment: You can look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44930845/3848632 by Kaloyan Kosev. I had the same problem and that works.

Answer (score 2):

Append the following code to `src/typings.d.ts`

```
declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

This will allow you to load `.json` modules.

You can view a full explanation here:
https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79

Comment: this doesn't solve the issue with npm test, try it out, it won't work